# First List change after remove

Tags: java, list

I have this code :

```
List<String> allAgenciesList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (AgencyEntryWithStatus agency : vAgencyEntryWithStatusList) {
    allAgenciesList.add(agency.getName() + "==" + agency.getId());
}

vRenameRuleXGlobalEntryList = vToolsDelegate.searchRenameRuleXGlobal(dStartDate2, dEndDate);
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (RenameRuleEntry rEntry : vRenameRuleEntryList) {
    RruleAgenciesGlobal rRuleAgenciesGlobalEntry = new RruleAgenciesGlobal();
    rRuleAgenciesGlobalEntry.setRr(rEntry);
    vRenameRuleXAgencyEntryList2 = vToolsDelegate.searchRenameRuleXAgency(dStartDate2, dEndDate, null, rEntry.getId());
    myList.clear();
    for (RenameRuleXAgencyEntry rAgency : vRenameRuleXAgencyEntryList2) {
        myList.add(rAgency.getAgencyName() + "==" + rAgency.getAgencyId());
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    if(!myList.isEmpty()) {
        String jsonAgencies = gson.toJson(myList);
        rRuleAgenciesGlobalEntry.setAgencies(jsonAgencies);
        allAgenciesList.removeAll(myList);
    }

    String jsonAgenciesNotAssigned = gson.toJson(allAgenciesList);
    rRuleAgenciesGlobalEntry.setAgenciesNotAssigned(jsonAgenciesNotAssigned);
}
```

The first for loop found 12 agencies and put them in a list called : allAgenciesList

In the second for loop if myList is not empty, we will do :
 allAgenciesList - myList

let say for the first iteration we found myList size == 2

so after :
    allAgenciesList.removeAll(myList); 12 -2 = 10 is the new size of  allAgenciesList

the problem is for next iteration I need  allAgenciesList to be complete with the initial element (size =12), BUT it has only 10 element (size == 10) instead of size == 12.
Please your help is appreciated.

Comment: You're removing elements from a list and then complain that those elements are missing???

Comment: Tl;dr, but have you tried to just duplicate `allAgenciesList` before you invoke the `removeAll()` method?

Comment: The code is very poorly formatted making it really tough to understand what's going on. But from what I understood, I think you could do with `CollectionUtils.removeAll` since it looks like you don't want to modify `allAgenciesList` at every turn. See [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List manipulations are persistant over loops. If you want to filter the elements from `myList` only temporarily, initialize a new temporary ArrayList as workset in each iteration of the inner loop:

```
List<String> allAgenciesList = new ArrayList<String>();
// [...]
for(RenameRuleEntry rEntry : vRenameRuleEntryList) {
    List<String> workset = new ArrayList<String>(allAgenciesList);
    // [...]
    // Work with workset instead of allAgenciesList from now on
}
```

`workset` is initialized with all entries from `allAgenciesList`, and will be fully populated again on the next iteration.

Comment: even if you work with workset, the same thing will happened, can you show me how in my code ? thanks

Comment: Look above, I have embedded the line in your code. If it still happens, you either have initialized the workset before the loop instead of within the loop, or you still call `allAgenciesList.removeAll(myList);` instead of `workset.removeAll(myList);`.

Answer (score 0):

Before removing the element, copy all the elements in another list like:

```
List<String> allAgenciesListCopy;//after allAgenciesList defination

....
List<String> allAgenciesListCopy = new ArrayList<String>(allAgenciesList);
allAgenciesList.removeAll(myList);
...
 allAgenciesList = allAgenciesListCopy;//here you will have all 12 elements instead of 10.
```

Comment: I'd not recommend to use the "backup restore" logic here. Codewise it is always cleaner to modify the copy itself and rather leave the original untouched than copying, modifying and restoring the original value.

Comment: But thing is OP might be doing something useful with his original list where he is expecting 10 items in the list which is why you cant avoid this.

Comment: de we need to clear allAgenciesList before :   allAgenciesList = allAgenciesListCopy;  ?

Comment: No not needed. This would be taken care by garbage collector.

Comment: even allAgenciesListCopy is changing, even there is no method called on it.

Comment: @almasshaikh If he did within the loop, the workset would also contain the 10 items, which is what I meant when I said "use the workset". If he did outside of the loop, your approach doesn't work either since you need to restore the list as the last instruction of the loop at least.

Comment: Yes that could be understood and hence i asked OP to update question with OP's latest code.